# Flutter - How to upload files to API?

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload

I am trying to post files (html files since working on web) to the API.
I am getting an error saying `Null` is not a subtype of type `InstanceRef` in type cast.
I don't know what is causing this. Everything seems to be fine to me in the code.

Here is the code:

```
          uploadFiles() async {
            ///
            try {
              var token =
                  'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIyIiwibmJmIjoxNjc5MzgzMTY5LCJleHAiOjE2NzkzODQ5NjksImlhdCI6MTY3OTM4MzE2OX0.HL5Y39p0cxpbuOhbls-hjq2Nu_xnVGAJ4qacESp1yNw';
              var url =
                  Uri.parse("my_url");
              var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
              Map<String, String> headers = {
                "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
                "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
              };
              request.headers.addAll(headers);

              request.fields
                  .addAll({"facility_id": "46", "module_id": "3263", "id": "1"});

              for (var file in files) {
                var reader = html.FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

                var completer = Completer<List<int>>();
                bool _isCompleted = false; // add this flag

                reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) {
                  if (!_isCompleted) {
                    // check if already completed
                    _isCompleted = true;
                    completer.complete(reader.result as List<int>);
                  }
                });
                var filename = file.name;
                var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                  'file',
                  (await completer.future),
                  filename: filename,
                );
                request.files.add(multipartFile);
              }

              var response = await request.send();

              if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                print('Upload successful');
              } else {
                print('Upload failed');
              }
            } //
            catch (e) {
              print(e);
            }
          }
```

Comment: Can you provide me with the complete stack-trace of the exception so that I can see exactly where it is breaking.

Comment: Also in this line `completer.complete(reader.result as List<int>);` , where is the complete function and what is it trying to do? I guess the excepption source could be invalid casting of reader.result as List<int>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
          ///
      Future<void> upload() async {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          final file = files[i];
          final completer = Completer<List<int>>();
          final reader = FileReader();

          reader.onLoad.listen((event) {
            final bytesData = reader.result as List<int>;
            completer.complete(bytesData);
          });

          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          final bytesData = await completer.future;
          final request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(url));
          final headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            "Content-Length": bytesData.length.toString(),
            "Accept": "*/*",
          };
          request.headers.addAll(headers);
          if (requestFields != null) {
            request.fields.addAll(requestFields!);
          }
          request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
            'files',
            bytesData,
            filename: file.name,
          ));
          final response = await request.send();
          handleResponse(response);
        }
      }
```

Turns out content-length was required.

Answer (score 0):

for file upload you should send with `"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"`

```
Future<int> uploadFile({File file,String filename,String token})async{
    ///MultiPart request
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST', Uri.parse("https://your api url with endpoint"),

    );
    Map<String,String> headers={
      "Authorization":"Bearer $token",
      "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    };
    request.files.add(
        http.MultipartFile(
           'file',
            file.readAsBytes().asStream(),
            file.lengthSync(),
            filename: filename,
          contentType: MediaType('image','jpeg'),
        ),
    );
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    /// optional if require to add other fields then image

    request.fields.addAll({
      "name":"test",
      "email":"test@gmail.com",
      "id":"12345"
    });
    print("request: "+request.toString());
    var res = await request.send();
    print("This is response:"+res.toString());
    return res.statusCode;
  }
}
```

Comment: nosuchmethod error for readAsBytes since it is a method for file from dart.io, I am on Flutter web which uses file from dart.html

Comment: @who-aditya-nawandar can you mention the package you're using to pick the image?

Comment: Edited the code, please check. Using http package.

Answer (score 0):

there are two possible way

> 1 - Multipart
> 2 - Base64Decode

```
static Future Uploadingusingmultipart({
    var courseid,
    var feedback,
    var filename,
  }) async {
    try {
      
      var request = http.MultipartRequest(
          'POST',
          Uri.parse(
              '${BaseUrl.baseurl}/apilink'));
      request.headers["authorization"] =  BaseUrl.storage.read("logintoken");

      request.fields['courseid'] =
          "${courseid}";
      request.fields['Feedback'] = "${feedback}";
      if (filename != '') {
        request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
            'Image', File(filename).readAsBytesSync(),
            filename: filename.split("/").last));
      }
      var res = await request.send();
      final response = await http.Response.fromStream(res);

      print(response.body);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      // return onError(e, "login/Users/login");
    }
  }
```

In this you upload  file using fileupload!.files.single.path,

```
Uploadingusingmultipart(
        courseid: fieldid,
        feedback: '',
        filename: fileupload!.files.single.path,
      )
```

The Other way is using Base64

```
 final bytes = File(pickedFile!.files.single.path).readAsBytesSync();
 String base64Image ="data:image/png;base64," +base64Encode(bytes);
```

In this you call api normally

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple solutions
Add and import library

```
 import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:async/async.dart';
convert XFile? imageURI; to file
Submit(File(imageURI!.path));
 
Submit(filepath) async { 
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest(
        "POST", Uri.parse('server url'));
    request.fields['user_id'] = UserId;
    request.fields['date_time'] = formatted;
    request.fields['current_address'] = address.text;
    if (filepath != null) {
      var stream =new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(filepath.openRead()));
      var length = await filepath.length();
      var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile(
          'location_image', stream, length,
          filename: path.basename(filepath.path));
      request.files.add(multipartFile);
    }
    var response = await request.send();
    print(response);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var response= await http.Response.fromStream(response);
      }
     }
  }'''''
```